# CSS-Grid with 4 columns and auto rows, how can I center a single element on final row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am hoping this will be a simple one, I have looked at the other submissions but they either are not what I am looking for or too complex, I have learning difficulty's so I have done my own simple code.

I have `.wrapper` which is 4 columns and `grid-auto-rows: 250px;`, If I populate the `.wrapper` with 4 DIV's then the first line is full, now if I add a 5th, this one goes onto a new row, however, it's to the left on the first column, is there anyway I can make the DIV's appear beginning at the center on that row?

In the end I made a separate .wrapper with 1 column.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}

.box {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use display: flex. Or do you want this to be done only with css grid?

Comment: I have never used display flex, I will have a look now, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want so  please take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/n4tyrhdL/
I just added `id="fifth-box"` in your **fifth div** 
and in css I put

```css
#fifth-box {
  grid-column: 2/ span 2; /* grid-column-start: 2; grid-column-end: 2;  */
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! :), thanks indefinite! :)

Comment: you can look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ for more information about css grid.